# IPhone and Android website design

Tags: iphone, android

How do you design and build your website to make it usable on both IPhone and Android, does it have to be pure html?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998916/creating-a-mobile-version-of-a-website , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816/help-on-website-optimization-for-iphone , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548892/tips-for-optimizing-a-website-for-androids-browser

Answer (score 2):

Both run modified webkit (the base of chrome and safari) based browsers.  They're capable of running full javascript.  You'll want to avoid using any browser plugins (like flash) since they're not really supported on these platforms.

They other big concern is the layout.  They don't have as much screen space as a typical computer screen and they don't have the same type of input devices.  Avoid requiring users to type a lot if it's not required.

Some Andriod phones and the iPhone also support HTML 5 so you can use its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your website should be designed in a way that it properly runs on chrome and safari, as they both are used by many users. The website should be compatible with smartphones as it will help in SEO strategies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31409438)